# How to capture option selected event in Material UI autocomplete component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am using the autocomplete component with filterOptions to suggest the creation of a new value as shown below:

```
<Autocomplete
        multiple
        name="participant-tags"
        options={people}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        renderInput={(params) => {
            return (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="Participants"
                />
            )
        }}
        filterOptions={(options, params) => {
            const filtered = filter(options, params);
            logger.debug('filterOptions(params) %j', params)

            // Suggest the creation of a new value
            if (params.inputValue !== '') {
                filtered.push({
                    inputValue: params.inputValue,
                    name: `Add "${params.inputValue}"`,
                });
            }

            return filtered;
        }}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
            if(e.keyCode === 13) {
                // TODO: select currently highlighted option
                e.preventDefault()
            }
        }}
        onChange={(e, value, reason) => {
            logger.debug(e.type)
            logger.debug(value)
            logger.debug(reason)
            e.preventDefault()
        }}
    />
```

However, I can't figure out where to handle the selection of the "Add this option" to actually add the option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved leveraging the 'reason' parameter in the onChange handler, and the onKeyDown handler isn't needed:

```
        filterOptions={(options, params) => {
            const filtered = filter(options, params);
            if (params.inputValue !== '') {
                filtered.push({
                    inputValue: params.inputValue,
                    [displayOptionsField]: `Add New ${newOptionLabel} "${params.inputValue}"`,
                });
            }
            return filtered;
        }}
        onChange={(e, value, reason) => {
            let newOptions
            if (reason==='select-option') {
                const last = value.pop();
                if (last.inputValue) {
                    newOptions = value.concat([{[displayOptionsField]: last.inputValue}])
                }
                else {
                    newOptions = value.concat([last])
                }
            }
            if (reason==='create-option') {
                const last = value.pop();
                newOptions = value.concat([{[displayOptionsField]: last}])
            }
            if (reason==='remove-option') {
                newOptions = value
            }
            if (newOptions) {
                onChange(newOptions)
            }
        }}
```

The onChange inside the onChange handler is there as a prop from a wrapping component.